# Mysql Select Recent items greater than or equal to today but limit to one date only

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE `fixtures` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2017-03-23',
  `goalsHomeTeam` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `goalsAwayTeam` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )
```

I want to get the items where date is either today or greater but whenever day matches it should only bring the items for that date only. So if I have 4 items in 23 Feb, and 3 items in 25 Feb, being both are greater than today I want only items for 23 Feb! 
I have tried

```
            SELECT * 
            FROM fixtures 
            WHERE date >= NOW();
```

But this brings both 23rd's and 25th's items!

Comment: add order by date asc limit 1;

Comment: @Surace that way, if OP had two items on the latest day, OP would only get one of them

Comment: @Surace I want all items in that same date! Limiting 1 will bring only one item

Comment: *"I want only items for 23 Feb"* - that contradicts the rest of your question. If you want today's date, remove the `>`.

Comment: Fred how does it? I want items that happens in 23 feb only

Comment: `WHERE date = NOW()` - run that with entries that are of "today" being Feb. 22 and you'll see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Fred-ii- the scenario is I want nearest items in the future! So if they are not today then show the nearest in the future! Got it?

Comment: Ok, well if you want to limit it to one day as per what your title reads *"but limit to one date only"* - Use a `GROUP BY` then. If not, then I'm not grasping the question.

Comment: SELECT * FROM fixtures  WHERE date IN (SELECT date FROM fixtures WHERE date > CURDATE() ORDER BY date asc LIMIT 1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the nearest date greater than today's date you can use the following query:

```
select min(date) from fixtures where date>current_date
```

or this:

```
select date from fixtures
where date>current_date
order by date limit 1
```

(current_date returns the current date without time information, so you can just use `>` instead of `>=`). Then your query will be like this:

```
select * from fixtures
where date=(select min(date) from fixtures
            where date>current_date)
```

Comment: Thanks your response works great and the one above works great now it comes to performance! Do you think your's or @Alex's response is optimum? I want to give credit to the most correct

Comment: @NaszNjokaSr. I think they will perform almost the same - but on this context, where just 1 date is returned, I prefer to use WHERE IN (subquery) - don't forget do add an index to the date column for optimal performances

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM fixtures f
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MIN(date) min_date
 FROM fixtures 
 WHERE date >= NOW()) filter
ON filter.min_date = f.date
```

Comment: Thanks your response works great and the one above works great now it comes to performance! Do you think your's or @fthiella's response is optimum? I want to give credit to the most correct

Comment: @NaszNjokaSr. you can check http://www.codersrevolution.com/blog/MySQL-performance-INNER-JOIN-vs-subselect but not sure if that article is correct in general

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fixtures 
WHERE date >= NOW() AND date = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM fixtures);
```

This will always return the elements from the smallest possible date you have stored in your database, which will always be today or greater than today.

Comment: invalid use of group function

Comment: Thanks for correcting it! But it still brings one item! If i have 2 items in 25th and 3 items in the 23rd! It should bring all items in 23rd

Comment: This way should return the items of the smallest date that matched.